# Why does the Clumsy armor tag impose −1 ongoing for all rolls?

Tags: dungeon-world

For example, why would it affect wisdom or intelligence?

...or am I just misunderstanding the rule?

Thank you!

Comment: Yes, welcome, good first question! Also, just for future reference, it's generally good practice to wait a couple of days before accepting an answer. It will tend to attract more and possibly better answers. In this case, Quentin wrote what I came here to write, so probably no harm done.

Comment: Cool thank you. I really dig this community. More forums should be structured this way.

Comment: @Jerimiah It's not a forum - it's a question-and-answer site ;) Woe upon he who tries to use Stack Exchange for open-ended discussions.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The practical answer is that a general −1 to everything is a simpler rule with less bookkeeping that makes the game run faster.

For an in-fiction explanation: Wearing clumsy armour is tiring, uncomfortable and distracting. These all make it harder to think straight and be alert.

Comment: That you! That's what I suspected.

Comment: If it does not give penalty to something, then someone will power-game it to abuse that :)

Comment: Also, if it gave a penalty only under certain circumstances, it could lead to a lot of arguments whether those circumstances are actually in effect in a certain situation or not.

Comment: It might be worth noting that while the -1 penalty is an explicit, mechanical part of the _Clumsy_ tag it's not the only thing it implies. If Armor is clumsy it's difficult for the character to wear and could feasibly be dangerous to them in some situations. A Fighter can probably haul themselves up a climbing rope while wearing plate armor with no problems but the weedy Wizard would be in serious danger if he tried the same, quite possibly prompting a **Defy Danger with STR** with the danger being a nasty fall or other injury.